# how to fit image inside a circular button objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I created a button in storyboard with a circular form using layer.cornerRadius in the key path. I want to add an image to it. How can I add an image to my button and the image is fit the same size of my button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to set image size to adjust button size:

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
btn.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; //set to fit button size
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

[buttonName setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Write the below code in viewDidAppear instead of viiewDidLoad

buttonName.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

buttonName.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the button height
```

Comment: [buttonName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fit image to Button :

```
UIButton *button =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 32)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// to set image to fit button size
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//ScaleToFill (UIViewContentModeScaleToFill)
//ScaleAspectFit (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit)
//ScaleAspectFill (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill)
```